# Web Services using Java on NetBeans

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, netbeans

Is this piece of code totally wrong? I am making a `web service` for a uni project. Is it possible to connect to a database while in a `web service` method.
The code of the connection works when in a standard SE project, but when in the web service the `NetBeans` will not let me deploy the project, it says it cannot create `WSDL`.

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.me.calculator;

```
 import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import javax.jws.WebService;
 import javax.jws.WebMethod;
 import javax.jws.WebParam;
 import javax.ejb.Stateless;

 /**
 *
 * @author ericman
  */
  @WebService(serviceName = "CalculatorWS")
  @ Stateless()
  public class CalculatorWS {


/**
 * Web service operation
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "UppDateBook")
public String UppDateBook(@WebParam(name = "name") String name) throws SQLException {
    //TODO write your implementation code here:
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bookcatalog","ericman","ericman");
    Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    String insert = "INSERT INTO `bookcatalog`.`books` (`name`, `isbn`, `price`, `publisher`, `img`) VALUES ('BookOne', '12456789', '45', 'publisher', 'httpfile');";
    int numUpdate = stmt.executeUpdate(insert);
    stmt.close();
    return null;
}
```

}

Error Message

> SEVERE: Unable to find adpater for endpoint 
>   WARNING: MEX0008:Failed to parse metadata returned from server at http://localhost:8080/WebSercviceOne/WebSercviceOne?WSDL/mex using protocol SOAP_1_1. Continuing attempts.
>   INFO: [ERROR] Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://localhost:8080/WebSercviceOne/WebSercviceOne?WSDL
>   Failed to read the WSDL document: http://localhost:8080/WebSercviceOne/WebSercviceOne?WSDL, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .
>   INFO: [ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s): 
>    At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.
>   INFO:   Failed to parse the WSDL.
>   INFO: Invoking wsimport with http://localhost:8080/WebSercviceOne/WebSercviceOne?WSDL
>   SEVERE: wsimport failed
>   INFO: Metro monitoring rootname successfully set to: amx:pp=/mon/server-mon[server],type=WSEndpoint,name=WebSercviceOne-WebSercviceOnePort
>   WARNING: Container org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSContainer@7339ea2c doesn't support class com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.Module
>   INFO: WS00019: EJB Endpoint deployed
>    ServiceOne  listening at address at http://ericman-PC:8080/WebSercviceOne/WebSercviceOne
>   INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [ServiceOne] at [/ServiceOne]
>   INFO: ServiceOne was successfully deployed in 511 milliseconds.
>   INFO: parsing WSDL...

Comment: WebServices can access the database for sure, I do on my own. We'll need more details on the exception. Maybe a stacktrace can help?

I really doubt that's the reason why is failing.

Comment: `Error generating artifacts for the following WSDL http://localhost:8080/CalculatorWS/CalculatorWS?WSDL

Possible causes can be invoking https when the application is not configured for security` This is what it says to me when i try to test the web service

Comment: Note: you shoud inject the DataSource/ EntityManager. Don't call DriverManager.getConnection.

Comment: Note: stick to the Java naming conventions: start method names with lower case.

Comment: "but when in the web service the NetBeans will not let me deploy the project, it says it cannot create WSDL." 

Can you explain this further. How do you deploy the WebService?

Comment: Sorry I meant test the web service

Comment: I updated the error code that glassfish give me

Comment: This is the error message you get when you call the WebService, right? Is there any error message when you deploy the WebService to GlassFish?

Answer (score 0):

You can't throw an exception that way, you need to create your own exceptions respecting theses points:
1) Your custom exception is a class that extends Exception.
2) add the tag @WebFault(name="exception name") to your exception class
3) Create a bean that saves the exceptio message this bean has a String argument with all the constructors and a getter.
4) Your exception class needs to have an attribute of that bean.
5) must have two constructors one with a message and an instance of the bean, the other with a message, the instance of the bean and a Throwable object representig the issue.